# How do I change the background color in xna

Tags: c#, xna

This code is in the update method, and I think that just means that this is what happens when the screen updates, but I'm not sure.I am wonder specifically about the lines of code 6-10. I am trying to make it so when the mouse is on the screen the screen turn green.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{

    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();
    MouseState current_mouse = Mouse.GetState();
    int mousep1 = current_mouse.X;
    int mousep2 = current_mouse.Y;
    if (current_mouse.X >= 0)
    {
        backcolor = Color.Green;
    }
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: are you using this 'backcolor' var somewhere ?

Comment: I think I actually found the solution. It was that I was not applying the backcolor var., so I guess to answer your question and mine I just had to use the var.. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the `Draw` method to use the variable when clearing the screen.

Make sure the `backcolor` variable is declared as a class level variable of type `Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Color`

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{           
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(backcolor);

    // Add Draw code here

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```